# Chance of guessing 5 out of 8 letters in sequence

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Everybody guessed or copied a word with 8 letters. • If someone had
> mutations at 3 of 8 positions from my word, there was a 1  chance
> 238,659 that they did not copy (they have written down 8-letter words
> with 3 different letters just by chance). • What if the class has 238,
> 659 people in it? • Then, even if everyone came up with their word
> randomly (and are therefore not related to each other) we would expect
> someone to have 3 mutations off my word, simply by chance.

That is an analogy given by my bioinformatics teacher but I have no idea where 238,659 is from.

I looked at permutation,
P(n,r) = P(26,8)
= 6.2999E + 10

Is the probability of guessing all 8 letters correctly in sequence I think.

So the chances of guessing 5 out of 8 correctly in sequence is a permutation or combination and can someone throw up the equation/formula or more importantly what is 238,659?

Edit:  My Professor is a very intelligent woman from China but her English is not so good.  I posted on the course forum asking where 238,659 comes from so hopefully she will clarify everything regarding cases, etc etc.  In the meanwhile, I thought there might be a simple explanation based on a few simple assumptions but I guess not.

Comment: First of all $238659 = 3 \times 19 \times 53 \times 79$.  Beyond that, normally I would edit your query to judiciously place line breaks.  Here I am scared to, because I don't want to garble your intent, which I can **not** at this moment decipher.  Questions: (1) Does each "letter" have exactly 26 independent possibilities (as if, there
is no distinction between upper case and lower case, and numbers are disallowed
and letters can repeat in the word)? (2) What **precisely** do you mean by
"mutations at 3 of 8 positions"? ...see next comment

Comment: (3) What does "...they did not copy..." signify?
Please do **not** respond by commenting.  Instead, please edit your query directly.
After that, if no one else responds, you can address a comment to @user2661923.

Comment: problem solved : see answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **was** able to reverse engineer what the solution, based on the number
238,659.  The key issue is: 
What constitutes a valid password?

Primary answer is : 
Letters only, not case sensitive.  So there are 26 different characters that can be used.

The OP made the natural presumption that letters may **not** be repeated.  Using the
OP's presumption, I could **not** reverse engineer the answer.

I then explored the opposite presumption:
Letters may be repeated in the password.  This presumption ended up explaining 238,659.

The number of possible passwords is $D = (26)^8.$

There are $F = \binom{8}{3} = 56$ choices, for which 3 of the 8 letters will be wrong.

The # of ways that these 3 letters can be wrong is $N = (25)^3$.

Therefore, the chances of getting exactly 3 wrong characters out of the 8 are:

$$P = F \times \frac{N}{D} = \frac{56 \times (25)^3}{(26)^8}.$$

$P$ is approximately

$$\frac{1}{238659.5024}.$$

Comment: yes, I'm sorry I should have clarified more as my teacher is making an analogy with gene/nucleotide sequences or protein sequences so yes repetition is allowed.

Comment: @webNoob13 Also, your posting indicated "...P(n,r) = P(26,8)..." which is relevant **only** when repeated letters are not allowed in the password.

Comment: I see, that is what I tried, not something the instructor showed us.  Sorry again for the confusion.